# Emacs: disable theme background color in terminal

Tags: emacs, colors, elisp

I'd like to have emacs not to have a background color when I open a frame in the terminal. I'm using a terminal with a translucent background, and characters with a background color are not "see-through". TERM is set to "xterm-256color".

How do I get emacs to use the default background color (no color at all), when the frame is not graphical?

**Edit:**
I've got it, sort of:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'my-awesome-theme t)

(defun on-frame-open (frame)
  (if (not (display-graphic-p frame))
    (set-face-background 'default "unspecified-bg" frame)))
(on-frame-open (selected-frame))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'on-frame-open)
```

I put the above code in my init file, but only suppresses the background when opening an emacsclient in a terminal, and not emacs itself (i.e. only when invoked with `emacsclient -t` and not when invoked with `emacs`). Adding an extra `(unless window-system (set-face-background 'default "unspecified-bg" (selected-frame)))` doesn't work and only confuses graphical frames.

Any ideas on why this might happen?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
(defun on-after-init ()
  (unless (display-graphic-p (selected-frame))
    (set-face-background 'default "unspecified-bg" (selected-frame))))

(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'on-after-init)
```

Combined with the code in your edit, it worked nicely for me for both emacsterms and newly started emacsen. As for why `window-setup-hook`: 
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html

(neither of the earlier hooks seemed to work except for this one.)

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly for me with iTerm2 + Emacs 24 + Base 16 theme.

Comment: Great little trick. I used it to apply a `wombat` theme only to terminal Emacs and not the windowed version where it does not look that nice.

Comment: Note that `(set-face-background 'default nil (selected-frame))` also works.

Comment: Awesome man!
Now I can use transparent background! (Ubuntu base terminal + Emacs25.2)

Comment: Emacs 27.2 on gnome-terminal, Fedora 34. Works like a charm !

Answer (score 5):

I tried the method that was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233611/5378450) but I had no luck getting it to work. this snippet works for me though

```
(defun on-frame-open (&optional frame)
  "If the FRAME created in terminal don't load background color."
  (unless (display-graphic-p frame)
    (set-face-background 'default "unspecified-bg" frame)))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'on-frame-open)
```

Although it has a setback, if the terminal has a different background settings than the theme I use (dark vs. light), default theme faces are being used which may not seem good on the light or dark background. but in my case which both terminal and theme are dark it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

There are already two answers to this question, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233611) using `window-setup-hook`, which is called on startup, and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298750) using `after-make-frame-functions`, which is called when a new frame is made, including after invoking `emacsclient`. To cover all possible cases, I found that I needed to do it this way:

```
(defun set-background-for-terminal (&optional frame)
  (or frame (setq frame (selected-frame)))
  "unsets the background color in terminal mode"
  (unless (display-graphic-p frame)
    (set-face-background 'default "unspecified-bg" frame)))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'set-background-for-terminal)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'set-background-for-terminal)
```

Note that I am only using `selected-frame` if necessary; it seems that in client mode, the hook is called before the frame is selected, so it is important to use the frame argument in that case.

Comment: There is a second for the transition of the color, is it normal?

Comment: I think it's normal for anything in your configuration to not load for a while, until Emacs gets to it.